# Using String function in xpath returns value and a new line

Tags: xpath

I am using the following format for my xpath expression in VB.Net workflow:

**String(xpath)**

which returns me the expected string value, but also a new line charac after the value which is breaking my logic.

How do I get rid of that new line?

Any pointers?

More Info as requested:

The normalize-space is still returning the new line.
The xml is too big, so pasting the snippet under its immediate parent here:

```
<Characteristic_Value_Population_Rule_SpecChar_Value_Population_Rule ID="f0baf095-5e84-4146-9c72-7691205df16b" xsi:type="SpecChar_Value_Population_Rule" Pattern="T_RelatedEntityRule">
    <Entity_T_RelatedEntityGroup_AND ID="a9adc94f-615b-477b-8841-94887429a83e" xsi:type="T_RelatedEntityGroup_AND" Pattern="TRelated_EntityGroup">
        <Entities_TRule_Value_EntityRef ID="f521569f-41a3-42ad-9974-3aea9557460b" xsi:type="TRule_Value_EntityRef" Pattern="TRule_Complex_Value">
            <Name>Modem ADSL/VDSL/TV/PSTN b-box 3 0</Name>
            <Entity>000006,000069,000078</Entity>
        </Entities_TRule_Value_EntityRef>
        <Entities_TRule_Value_EntityRef ID="9025dfc0-bd7d-4252-8dad-f95a818b8688" xsi:type="TRule_Value_EntityRef" Pattern="TRule_Complex_Value">
            <Name>Modem ADSL/VDSL2/TV/Italk/off b-box 2 039</Name>
            <Entity>000006,000069,000077</Entity>
        </Entities_TRule_Value_EntityRef>
        <Name>Acquisition Type is Rent in the context of Belgacom Internet</Name>
    </Entity_T_RelatedEntityGroup_AND>
    <Name>Acquisition Type is Rent in the context of Belgacom Internet</Name>
    <Characteristic ID="ae3f9304-31a7-4c0b-8723-c553b136410e" Pattern="TSpecChar" OrigType="SpecCharItem">
        <Specification_Characteristic ID="c5dec18e-806c-46d1-8294-e83117650b5b" Pattern="TSpecCharValue" OrigType="SpecCharValueItem">
            <Value>Rent</Value>
            <IsUserDefinedValue>false</IsUserDefinedValue>
        </Specification_Characteristic>
        <Name>Acquisition Type</Name>
    </Characteristic>
</Characteristic_Value_Population_Rule_SpecChar_Value_Population_Rule>
</Package>
```

I am trying to get the value **c5dec18e-806c-46d1-8294-e83117650b5b** which the xpath expression does return but with the new line.

i am now using the xpath:
string(normalize-space(//Package/Characteristic_Value_Population_Rule_SpecChar_Value_Population_Rule/Characteristic/Specification_Characteristic/@ID))

Comment: If the attribute value does not contain a new line then XPath will not add one. In the sample the `ID="c5dec18e-806c-46d1-8294-e83117650b5b"` does not show any new line and doing `string(//Package/Characteristic_Value_Population_Rule_SpecChar_Value_Population_Rule/Characteristic/Specification_Characteristic/@ID)` should give you the value `c5dec18e-806c-46d1-8294-e83117650b5b`. If you have a new line then the problem is elsewhere or the input is different. Which API do you use to evaluate the XPath expression in VB?

Answer (score 0):

Try `String(normalize-space(xpath))`. If that does not help then show us more context.